# How do I append a list of external group policy settings to pre-existing group policy?

Tags: windows, group-policy

Currently, I am trying to find a way to append new group policies to group policy that already exists on my computer.  I know that you can find group policy in the directory, `%windir%\System32\GroupPolicy\Machine\Registry.pol` or `%windir\System32\GroupPolicy\User\Registry.pol` (Note: this directory will be empty if you have not opened gpedit.msc on your computer yet, and the Machine and Users folders will be empty until you set a value in gpedit.msc).  However, there seem to be no options to adding new policies to policy that already exists in this area.

I have tried to copy and paste the contents from an external Registry.pol file without the header, PReg, to the Registry.pol file on the host, but doing so either doesn't change anything (if you edit it with a unix text editor) or makes group policy return an error (if you edit it with something like windows notepad).  LGPO also has no options to append policy to a computer.

Is there any method that I have been missing that can be used for importing group policy, or something else that you can do with the Registry.pol file to append group policy?